# PHP Sorting Multidimensional Array Sorted by Weight

Tags: php, sorting, matrix

I just asked this question a moment ago but I asked incorrectly so I apologize.

I'm hoping there's an easy way to do this without tons and tons of loops.

I have a matrix in the following manner:

```
      Foo1    Foo2    Foo3 ....   FooN
Jan    1       8       5            4
Feb    10      12      15          11
Mar    12      7       4            3
Apr    10      16      7           17
```

Assuming the following array:

```
$arrayMonths = array(
       'jan' => array(1, 8, 5,4)
       'feb' => array(10,12,15,11)
       'mar' => array(12, 7, 4, 3)
       'apr' => array(10,16,7,17)
    );
```

I need to sort the above array and show it in the following manner:

```
array[apr][FooN] = 17
array[feb][Foo3] = 15
array[mar][Foo1] = 12
array[jan][Foo2] = 8
```

Essentially, I need to get the greatest sum of the above weights, one month can only have one foo and one foo can only have one month.  In the above example, the result would be 52.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Demo : http://codepad.org/vDI2k4n6

```
$arrayMonths = array(
       'jan' => array(1, 8, 5,4),
       'feb' => array(10,12,15,11),
       'mar' => array(12, 7, 4, 3),
       'apr' => array(10,16,7,17),
    );

$position = array("Foo1","Foo2","Foo3","FooN");
$set = array();

foreach($arrayMonths as $key => $value)
{
    $max = max($value);
    $pos = array_search($max, $value);
    $set[$key][$position[$pos]] = $max ;
}


function cmp($a, $b)
{
    foreach($a as $key => $value )
    {
        foreach ($b  as $bKey => $bValue)
        {
            return $bValue - $value ;
        }
    }

}

uasort($set,"cmp");
var_dump($set);
```

Output

```
    array
      'apr' => 
        array
          'FooN' => int 17
      'feb' => 
        array
          'Foo3' => int 15
      'mar' => 
        array
          'Foo1' => int 12
      'jan' => 
        array
          'Foo2' => int 8
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) is the key here:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($array as $row) {
  $sum += max($row);
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$totalArr = array();
$total = 0;

foreach($arrayMonths as $month => $row)
{
    $high = max($row);
    $totalArr[$month]['foo'] = $high;
    $total += $high;
}

echo "Total is: " . $total . "\n\n";
print_r($totalArr);
```

**Outputs:**

```
Total is: 52

Array
(
    [jan] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 8
        )

    [feb] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 15
        )

    [mar] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 12
        )

    [apr] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 17
        )

)
```

Use `uasort()` if you want to sort the new array.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Answer (score 0):

Look into this way of doing it. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Input the array and a reference to a comparison function that you write yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr_new = array();
foreach(array_keys($arrayMonths) as $h) {

    $int_max = max($arrayMonths[$h]);
    foreach(array_keys($arrMonths[$h]) as $h2)
        if ($arrMonths[$h][$h2] == $int_max) {

            $arr_new[$h]["foo{$h2}"] = $int_max;
            break;

        }

}
```